# vb.net Network Programming - List Network Interfaces

Tags: vb.net, network-programming

I am somewhat new to VB.net and attempting to pull all network interface status and display it in a ListBox.

I am able to pull the Network Interface Card name, and MAC address and list them in the first 2 columns.

However, when pulling the other data I am faced with an exception:

> Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of
>   the collection.  Parameter name: index

Can someone explain to me what exactly is happening here, and point me in the right direction?

I have the following code:

```
Imports System.Net.NetworkInformation

Public Class networkInterfaces
Private Sub showNetInts_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles showNetInts.Click
    getInterfaces()
End Sub

Private Sub getinterfaces()
    Dim nics As NetworkInterface() = NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces()

    If nics.Length < 0 Or nics Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox("No network interfaces found.")
    End If

    netInterfaces.Items.Clear()

    For Each netadapter As NetworkInterface In nics
        'get interface properties
        Dim intProperties As IPInterfaceProperties = netadapter.GetIPProperties

        netInterfaces.Items.Add(netadapter.Name)

        Dim physAddr As PhysicalAddress = netadapter.GetPhysicalAddress
        Dim addbyte As Byte() = physAddr.GetAddressBytes

        Dim macAddr As String = ""
        'loop through bytes value and change value to hex
        For i = 0 To addbyte.Length - 1
            macAddr &= addbyte(i).ToString("X2") 'changes string to hex
            'separate hex value with "-", except last value
            If i <> addbyte.Length - 1 Then
                macAddr &= "-"
            End If
        Next

        Dim icount As Integer = netInterfaces.Items.Count

            With netInterfaces.Items(icount - 1).SubItems
            .Add(macAddr)
            .Add(intProperties.UnicastAddresses(1).Address.ToString) ' 2 index = ipv4 addr
            .Add(intProperties.UnicastAddresses(1).IPv4Mask.ToString) ' gets mask addr
            .Add(intProperties.UnicastAddresses(0).Address.ToString) ' 0 index - ipv6 addr

    Next
```

Comment: That exception indicates that you were trying to get an item at index A from a list with lower bound B and upper bound C where A is not in the range B to C.  The first thing to do is to determine what the invalid index was.  The next step is to determine what the valid range was.  The next step is to determine where that invalid index came from.  Once you know those three things, you can try to correct the problem.  If you can't fix it on your own, you can give us all that relevant information and we can try to help from there.

Comment: Actually, before that even, the first step is always to determine exactly which line the exception is being thrown on.  That is information that you ALWAYS need to provide in your question when asking about an exception.

Comment: I updated my code, trying to pull where the error occurs at, and receive a line: 0.

Comment: What I am understanding is that the index being pulled from is 'nics'. Once again quite new to this, any assistance is appreciated. Full code posted.

Comment: I would suggest that you simply remove the exception handling altogether (for the time being at least) and then the IDE will show you exactly what line the exception was thrown on.  Also, if you are using a Debug build with PDB files available then the exception stack trace will give you line numbers.

Comment: I found that the exception is at: .Add(intProperties.UnicastAddresses(2).Address.ToString) ' 2 index = ipv4 addr ... investigating.

Comment: Okay so I have adjusted the code to pull from the correct index. It appears that if it returns a blank entry, the exception is thrown. It is pulling a virtual interface with no ip address on it. Suggestions?

Comment: Unless there's something in the `NetworkInterface` object that identifies such instances, I'd suggest that you just put those last three `Add` calls inside an `If` block that tests `intProperties.UnicastAddresses.Any()`.  `Any` will return `False` for an empty list and `True` otherwise.

Comment: I actually already tried that, with no success.

Comment: I don't see how that could possibly be the case, unless you actually mean that there's only one item in the collection and so 1 is an invalid index.  If so then you just need two nested `If` blocks, with the outer one checking whether the `Count` is greater than 0 and the inner one checking whether it's greater than 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of what I mean by this:

> If so then you just need two nested If blocks, with the outer one
>   checking whether the Count is greater than 0 and the inner one
>   checking whether it's greater than 1.

```
If intProperties.UnicastAddresses.Count > 0 Then
    If intProperties.UnicastAddresses.Count > 1 Then
        .Add(intProperties.UnicastAddresses(1).Address.ToString) ' 2 index = ipv4 addr
        .Add(intProperties.UnicastAddresses(1).IPv4Mask.ToString) ' gets mask addr
    End If

    .Add(intProperties.UnicastAddresses(0).Address.ToString) ' 0 index - ipv6 addr
End If
```

Comment: That did it! I was trying to wrap it in a single if statement. Thank you so much for the help.